# How to configure .htaccess to run a php script whenever someone accesses the site?

Tags: php, mysql, html, apache, .htaccess

I need to configure the .HTACCESS file so that every time someone accesses any file or directory of the site, a php script is executed and this script is informed of the requested file (sent to the browser). What is the simplest way to accomplish this?
I need to create an access statistics table, using data from the IP that it accesses. On the sites I created, I simply put on each page a call to the database record. But on this occasion, I'm dealing with a Word Press site. That's a lot of files, and I would not dare change them.
Therefore I intend to use this method: Have HTACCESS collect the request data and run the php script that will register the DB.

Comment: Using apache logs is simpler, safer, and take less resources.

Comment: But with apache log would it be possible to register the data in a table (mysql), to stylize the data on a page and present it to the client?

Comment: Do you this at every page invocation? You are not inventing anything new. Often a program is run regularly to update statistics, and an other program is used to display things. And you don't get limits on mysql connections and slowdown because various processes are trying to write to mysql at the same time.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi apache logs would be far less simple than utilizing the request information passed to php. Apache logs would require data filtering and massaging, and might not give you the detail you may need.

Comment: Look at the table in this link and you will understand that what I am doing is very different from Apache Logs.
http://eibo.com.br/imagens/estatisticas.html

Comment: @Al.UrBasebelonTomeh: It is your choice, one stuff is data gathering, an other is data preparation. Usually such things are done with apache log, so that you can analyze data (aggregating data, finding session times, etc.) and get geoIP without slowing down connection from users, or on display statistics. Additionally, images and CSS are not shown on actual statistics, nor access to robots.txt, so you never know if it was an user or one of the numerous bot. With mysql down, you can also no more display any kind of information/error.

Comment: I understand your position, in many hosting accounts the Apache Logs are accessible to the user. It is not the case of my shared hosting account (HostGator), which only provides such LOGS by opening a service order (ticket), and explanations of the reason for the request. Each case is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess file, replacing `/path_to_file/file.php` with your file's path

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/path_to_file/file.php"
```

Comment: It really worked! Thank you! This will help a lot in this project.